# Error de conexión a BD cuando pruebo en un servidor ubuntu pero funciona con XAMPP en windows

Tags: php, sql

Tengo el siguiente problema, diseñe un programa PHP que funciona a la perfección en un servidor local windows generado con xampp, ahora cuando lo migro a un servidor linux ubuntu, noto que me tira un error de conexión cuando trato de hacer un insert, en mysql, el codigo es:

```
$campos=array();

foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
        if($k != "btn1"){
            if ($v !=""){
                $campos[]="$k='$v'"; 
            }
        }
}

$consulta = $conexion -> query ("INSERT INTO alta_cliente SET ".implode(", ", $campos)) or die ("Ha fallado la conexión");
```

Resumiendo esta sentencia en xampp Windows anda perfecto, guarda los datos que vienen por post y en linux no.

Clase conexion:

```
 <?php $host = "localhost"; // sera el valor de nuestra BD 
 $basededatos = "sgc1"; // sera el valor de nuestra BD 
  $usuariodb = "root"; // sera el valor de nuestra BD 
 $clavedb = ""; // sera el valor de nuestra BD error_reporting(0); //No me muestra errores 
 $conexion = new mysqli($host,$usuariodb,$clavedb,$basededatos); 
 if ($conexion->connect_errno) 
 { echo "Nuestro sitio experimenta fallos...."; 
 exit(); 
 } ?>
```

Comment: agrega tu clase de conexion

Comment: <?php 
 $host = "localhost";    // sera el valor de nuestra BD 
 $basededatos = "sgc1";    // sera el valor de nuestra BD 
 $usuariodb = "root";    // sera el valor de nuestra BD 
 $clavedb = "";    // sera el valor de nuestra BD 

 error_reporting(0); //No me muestra errores
 
 $conexion = new mysqli($host,$usuariodb,$clavedb,$basededatos);


 if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
     echo "Nuestro sitio experimenta fallos....";
     exit();
 }

?>

Comment: puedes ver la causa del error ejecutando   `sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: Intenta agregar la traza de errores `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Intenta creando un usuario mysql y dale privilegios sobre la bd

Comment: hola muchas gracias por su respuesta, cuando pongo la linea de para que me diga los errores me da un error copio codigo                 $consulta = $conexion -> query ("INSERT INTO alta_cliente SET ".implode(", ", $campos)) or die (
                ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
                ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
                error_reporting(E_ALL);
                 "Ha fallado la conexión");

Comment: hola, muchas gracias por sus comentarios, hice un codigo muy simple y el error esta en esta linea $consulta = $conexion -> query ("INSERT INTO alta_cliente SET ".implode(", ", $campos)) or die ("Ha fallado la conexión"); el nuevo codigo que probe en xampp windows anda bien y en linux no, este es el codigo, include("abrir_conexion.php");

 $conexion->query("INSERT INTO $tabla_db1 (nombre,dni) values ('$nombre','$dni')") or die ("falla en la conexion"); si alguien me puede dar una mano lo agradeceria

Comment: cree otro usuario y le di todos los privilegios, y tampoco....